# Performance of encrypted stored procedures

Tags: sql-server

Is there a performance difference between encrypted stored procedures and unencrypted ones?

Comment: http://bytes.com/topic/sql-server/answers/642361-where-conditions-encryption says not really

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be.  If there wasn't the encryption/decryption wasn't doing anything.  The overhead should, however, be a constant time slight overhead, and should be negligible in larger transactions.